# How to set up opengl on a dual graphics card laptop

Tags: graphics, opengl, mesa

I'm having trouble in getting newer version opengl.

First, I get my graphics cards information using:  `lspci -nnk | grep VGA` and it returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18)
```

and

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520M] [10de:1050] (rev a1)
```

When I use: `glxinfo | grep Op` command, it returns

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get new driver to use a newer version mesa? I installed mesa 9.1.5, but it's not shown in glxinfo.
2. how do I use my nvidia graphics card ?

I installed nvidia-current and bumblebee. 
I tried optirun to run a program, it worked at first, but then it crashed when I ran it again. Since I want a newer version of opengl and mesa only only supports opengl 3.1.

btw:the crash information is:

```
[  157.097081] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

[  157.097158] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

How do I get opengl 4.1 or newer development package?

My laptop information (from the tag):

Acer Aspire 4743G

Intel Core i5-480m

2GB DDR3 memory

Comment: Can you add the computer specifications (make, model and ram) to your question bu clicking the Edit link, just under your question :)